# Set theory, relation between intersection and union of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm having troubles with this problem regarding the set theory, which should be pretty simple, though I don't know where to start.

Let $A_{1 j} := R × [ j − 1, j ]$ and $A_{1 j} := [ j − 1, j ] × R$, for j = 1, 2.

Let $B=:\bigcup_{m=1}^2 \bigcap_{n=1}^2 A_{mn}$ and $C=:\bigcap_{n=1}^2 \bigcup_{m=1}^2 A_{mn}$. Which of the
following is true: B ⊂ C and/or C ⊂ B? Why?

At first glance, I would say that C=B since the order doesn't change the fact that the intersection of sets should include the smoller set, although the letters get me confuse (becouse the first statement use j and not m or n).
I hope someone might be able to solve it.
Thanks

Comment: You are defining $A_{1j}$ twice as different products. Should one of them be $A_{j1}$?

Comment: You haven't defined what $A_{21}$ and $A_{22}$ are

Comment: And what is $R$? Did you mean $\mathbb{R}$, the set of Real numbers?

Comment: Given that each operation has only two elements, maybe it helps you if you write them with the binary operators, for example $\bigcap_{n=1}^2 A_{mn} = A_{m1}\cap A_{m2}$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, R is the set of real numbers, and the second A is A2j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I believe you made a typo, since you defined $A_{1j}$ twice, so I'll assume you meant:*

\begin{align}
A_{1,j}&=R\times [j-1,j]\\
A_{2,j}&=[j-1,j]\times R
\end{align}

*Furthermore, the question only seems relevant if $R=\mathbb R$ is the set of real numbers.*

---

Now, the notation $\bigcup_{i=1}^k X_k$ means the same thing as $X_1\cup X_2\cup\dots\cup X_k$, if $k$ is a natural number. A similar thing holds for $\bigcap$. Therefore we can write $B$ and $C$ as follows:

\begin{align}
B&=\bigcup _{m=1}^2\bigcap_{n=1}^2 A_{m,n}\ =\ \bigcup _{m=1}^2\,(A_{m,1}\cap A_{m,2})\ =\ (A_{1,1}\cap A_{1,2})\cup(A_{2,1}\cap A_{2,2})\\
C&=\bigcap _{n=1}^2\bigcup_{m=1}^2 A_{m,n}\ =\ \bigcap _{n=1}^2\,(A_{1,n}\cup A_{2,n})\ =\ (A_{1,1}\cup A_{2,1})\cap(A_{1,2}\cup A_{2,2})
\end{align}

Let's first compute $A_{1,1}\cap A_{1,2}$:

\begin{align}
A_{1,1}\cap A_{1,2}&=\mathbb R\times[0,1]\ \cap\ \mathbb R\times[1,2]
\end{align}
Now an element of $A_{1,1}$ is a pair of numbers $(x,y)$ such that $x\in \mathbb R$ is any real number, and $y\in[0,1]$ is a real number $0\leq y\leq 1$. When is such an element part of $A_{1,2}$? Only if $y\in[1,2]$ as well, so $1\leq y\leq 2$ needs to hold. But then $1\leq y\leq 1$, so $y=1$. Therefore $A_{1,1}\cap A_{1,2}$ contains only those numbers $(x,1)$ for $x\in\mathbb R$. In other words, $A_{1,1}\cap A_{1,2}=\mathbb R\times\{1\}$.

Doing this for all pairs, we see:
\begin{align}
A_{1,1}\cap A_{1,2}&=\mathbb R\times\{1\}\\
A_{2,1}\cap A_{2,2}&=\{1\}\times \mathbb R\\
A_{1,1}\cup A_{2,1}&=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x\in[0,1]\text{ or }y\in[0,1]\}\\
A_{1,2}\cup A_{2,2}&=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x\in[1,2]\text{ or }y\in[1,2]\}
\end{align}

Therefore we get:

\begin{align}
B&=\ \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x=1\text{ or }y=1\}\\
C&=\ \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x=1\text{ or }y=1\}\ \cup\  [0,1]\times[1,2]\ \cup\ [1,2]\times[0,1]
\end{align}

So we see that $B\subset C$

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I'm still not understanding the last passage: the union between R x (1) and (1) x R shouldn't be R?

Comment: @Akai You're right, my bad, I've corrected my answer. It shouldn't be $\mathbb R^2$, as $(2,2)$ is in neither of the two parts of the union.

Comment: I would have said R^2, I mean if R is in x values in the first product and y values in the second, shouldn't be RxR the union of this two?

Comment: No, the cartesian product of two sets is a set of pairs, which $\mathbb R$ is not, so this couldn't be possible. Elements of $\mathbb R\times\{1\} $ look like $(x, 1) $ for $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Also, note that $\mathbb R^2$ is alternative notation for $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$, they're the same thing.

Comment: Right, I get it, I didn't see the 'or' in the answer. Thanks

Comment: I just try to do the exercise again; please, note that the order of m and n is opposite between B and C, so I ween C should be: C=(1,1), so that C should be a subset of B.

Comment: @AkaiM Totally correct, I must've been somewhere else with my head when typing the answer. You're correct, if $m$ and $n$ switch places, then $B\subset C$ is generally provable.

Comment: Sorry, one more question: why C became like that? Since it is an intersection I thought it would've been just (x,y | for x=1 or y=1)...

Comment: There are two possible conditions per set in the intersection ($x\in [0,1]$ or $y\in[0,1]$ for the first set) and ($x\in[1,2]$ or $y\in[1,2]$ for the second set). In the intersection, the conditions for both sets need to be true, so that gives four options; (both $x\in[0,1]$ and $x\in[1,2]$, giving $x=1$) or (both $y\in[0,1]$ and $y\in[1,2]$, giving $y=1$) or ($x\in[0,1]$ and $y\in[1,2]$) or ($x\in[1,2]$ and $y\in[0,1]$).